# Getting 'Make sure that all fields are correct to continue' error while creating Windows 11 image on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-10, windows-11, google-cloud-console, google-cloud-compute-engine

Error getting Windows 11 working on Google Cloud

I have uploaded and created my own Windows 11 image, with my own licence.

[Showing Windows11 Image being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qynHQ.png)

After filling out all of them details and boxes that I can visible see, even opened all of the advanced menus to see if I am missing something, I get a 'Make sure that all fields are correct to continue' error when trying to create it, I've tried making one 3 times now, all with double checking every entry box.

['Make sure that all fields are correct to continue' error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Glug.png)

But at least to my eyes, everything is there, with how they should be? Am I missing something? Any help please!

I was trying to create a Windows 11 VM to use for software testing, and since like stated above it failed. I have even tried using Windows 10 as well.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use your own license key for Windows 11. Google validates Microsoft licenses and that requires that you have a contract with Microsoft. Did you complete the `license verification form`? Also, you will have many challenges trying to get Windows 11 to run in the cloud on a Google VM. I know Windows internals well and I would not even try to get it to work.